# The wrong styles bundle path

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a angular 4 app with angular-cli aot, and I build the prod version on azure web app
I noticed that on some pages styles bundle try to find it by relative path
As result I see next error in console:

```
GET http://example.com/en/styles.b0bf326c21a7f4ee7e7f.bundle.css net::ERR_ABORTED
```

in the html I see that css doesn't start from "/":

```
<link href="styles.b0bf326c21a7f4ee7e7f.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

How I can fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build)

--deploy-url (aliases: -d)

URL where files will be deployed.

```
node ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --deploy-url /
```

Comment: Thank you! I had the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49304086/angular-4-universal-ssr-style-not-loaded-right-when-using-url-with-folders/49393776#49393776

Comment: can you clarify further. I am not able to achieve