# Angular 4 & Universal SSR - Style not loaded right when using URL with folders

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I have webpage that using Angular 4. 
When accessing using domain base i.e. www.mydomain.com site loads right.

When accessing using url folder i.e. www.mydomain.com/folder/page the styles are not loaded from right place:
www.mydomain.com/folder/styles.[hash].bundle.css 
I'm getting 200 http but not the right css response. Thus my site looks without css.

Inside my index.html I have this line:

```
<head>
  <base href="/">
```

That still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution here:
[The wrong styles bundle path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46737135/the-wrong-styles-bundle-path)

That worked for me. Since I used Universal SSR I had to change this line:

```
ng build --prod --deploy-url / && ng build --prod --app 1 --output-hashing=false
```

By adding `--deploy-url /`

Comment: can you clarify further. I am not able to achieve